# Amplifier has no aux in, what alternatives can I use?

Tags: guitar, practice, amplifiers

As stated my amplifier has no Aux in jack. It's hindering me from practicing with an otherwise (imo) great amp (a Vox Pathfinder 15r).

Been  thinking of using this to interface between the music player and my amplifier since the pathfinder 15r has a mono lineout: [Tascam CD GT1 mk2](http://www.dolphinmusic.co.uk/shop_image/product/5462-tascam-cd-gt1-mk2-large.jpg)

or maybe this? [USB Guitar Link](http://alpha.akihabaranews.com/wp-content/uploads/images/7/17/24217//1.jpg)

thoughts?

Comment: What do you want to connect to your amp, other than a guitar?

Comment: I have an effects chain where in I connect my guitar into, that goes directly into the amplifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different answer. I used  to use a Tascam,and the chain was gtr - Tascam - amp., which is probably the path you mean. Yes, it'll work.The CD player in the Tascam will obviously let you play CDs,and you can plug the output from mp3 etc. into 'line in' on the Tascam. Be aware that the balance between inputs  may be possible but you'll need to change the gain via the output source.  All this will work, and the effects will only colour the guitar sound, so no real need to add an effects unit into the chain.  If you did, it'd be gtr - effects - Tascam - amp.If all fails, read the instructions,which are fiddly to follow, but help tremendously.

Comment: oh okay, that's nice. how about guitar-effects-amplifier-tascam? then the music source would be plugged into the tascam as well, all mixed into one line out for headphones?

Comment: how about mixing everything into a ABY box? would that be to the same effect without tone coloration?

Comment: I think it says don't plug amps into Tascam, but it'll be on the instructions.If you need to use cans, cut out the amp.

Comment: Ahh, didn't know about that part! thanks for the heads up. Looks like using the tascam is a no go then, unless I do your suggestion of putting the tascam before the amplifier, problem I think though is the music would mix into the amp and would be getting the same eq settings and what not from the amplifier.

Comment: just read the manual and indeed I can't connect an amplifier to it. whew good thing I havent purchased the unit yet.

Comment: It just means you shouldn't connect the speaker output from an amp - because it'll be too loud a signal. Line-out into line-in is fine. The Tascam doesn't know what device the line out came from!

Comment: ahh so that's how it works, and so I learn. the pathfinder 15r has a mono line out on the back of it. which should go into the 3.5mm line in. also after reading the manual it says that the line in accepts a pre amp, which means it can also accept an amplifier also?

Comment: The manual is just giving you examples of things that the line level signal might come from. Line level is line level. The input doesn't care what's on the other end of the wire. It only cares that the peak voltages are within line level range.

Comment: ahh so I can assume that an amplifier would work with it then. I was looking into small mixers and found this [behringer 302](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/302USB.aspx) also this [one](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/UFO202.aspx) looks like this would answer my needs?

Comment: That, or any mixer, from Behringer, will be fine, in my opinion.Used them for years with no problems.The Tascam is more of a pre-amp. than an amp, so it's not going to cause you problems.

Answer (score 7):

The USB guitar link is for recording your guitar into a computer. Useful, but not relevant to your needs here.

To play something like a CD player through a guitar amp, it is sometimes enough to connect the headphone output of the CD player, to the instrument input of the amp. You will need to turn the headphone volume right down, and turn down the gain/distortion on the amp - because the amp will distort a strong signal. Remember a guitar amp is *designed to* colour and distort the sound.

However, if what you want to do is practice alongside recorded backing music, you would probably be better off letting your guitar amp do what it's good at -- amplifying a guitar -- and have the backing music come from a separate amp and speaker. A cheap boombox or a set of PC speakers would be fine.  This way you can adjust the tone of your guitar, without affecting the backing music.

---

If you plug your guitar into the guitar amp, connect the amplifier's line-out to the Tascam's line-in, and listen to the output of your Tascam through headphones (or some other amp/speaker setup -- one designed not to distort or colour) -- then you are effectively using your guitar amp as a bulky effects pedal.

That's fine, but note that some of the tonal qualities provided by the guitar amp come from the physical build of the speaker and cabinet, and of course if you're not using those, you don't get the benefit from them.

Comment: I think it should be stressed that the music player will sound horrible coming out of the amp, especially with the gain/distortion dialed up.

Comment: I see. So my option of using the tascam as an interface between the guitar amplifier, and then the music player will just color my tone more and in the end won't help me at all won't it? Also, if I were to plug the USB guitar link to a wallsocket wouldn't it serve as some sort of splitter that accepts the signal from the guitar and from the mp3 player?

Comment: @galley: The USB link into an wall socket would combine the signals from the guitar and MP3 player, and send them into the wall... The output is the USB plug with purpose to record on a computer using some recording software.

Comment: looks like it didn't even notice that there wasn't any aux in for that device lol.

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest option would be to replace the amp with one that has an aux in.That way, the impedences for gtr. and mp3 or whatever are better balanced, and individually controllable for volume, tone etc.Provided you eq. your own amp, the sound will not be as awful as suggested - guitar amps WILL produce clean sounds when the gain is not excessive.Or, find another practice amp just for the backing tracks - 10 / 15 watts will be ample.Or, buy a small mixer - Behringer do great ones, and feed gtr in one channel and sounds through another.Problem with that is - if you want distortion on gtr., you'll have it on the other sound source as well.Good luck.

Comment: ahhh, this seems close to my plan of using a tascam cd gt1 to sit between the amplifier and the music player then right? worried though that it will just color my tone since the tascam cd gt1 is also an amplifier